# Radix sort over linked lists

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Given a linked list of unsigned long integers, how would you sort the list using radix sort? In addition, allocating a pointer array for each bucket being used?

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would sort them exactly as strings (prepending 0 to set them to equal length) a use [radix sort procedure](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/40868/Radix-sort)...